# Is there an app to quickly download and install a list of non-App Store apps?

Tags: install, applications

Now that the Mac App Store exists, if an app is available there I prefer to buy it there instead of on the developer's site. This has several advantages, but the one that I've been enjoying recently is the ability to sign into the store on a new or freshly wiped Mac, go through my list of purchases, and click "Install" next to each app I want to reinstall. Leave the computer for a bit, come back, and they're all installed and waiting for me in /Applications.

However, there are a number of non-App Store apps that I like to reinstall as well. Some, like Transmission, would not be allowed in the App Store for rule violations, and others, like VLC, are kept out because of license issues. Is there an app that I can use that acts similarly to the Mac App Store app, but allows me to quickly and easily download and install third-party apps?

There's a service for Windows and Linux called [Ninite](http://ninite.com/) that seems to do this, but they don't appear to have a Mac version. Another possibility is [AppBodega](http://appbodega.com/), but it doesn't seem to have the concept of an "account" so I'd have to still remember and hunt through the list of apps in the app.

Answer (score 2):

One solution could be to use [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com). Instead of installing your applications to the Applications folder, you can install them to the Dropbox folder instead. The only drawback is that some of the applications data may not be copied over unless you mess around with the settings and folders the data is stored in. However, this may not be an issue with applications that don't have many settings, such as VLC.

Answer (score 2):

[MacUpdate](http://www.macupdate.com/) may have the feature you are looking for. It has a list of over 30,000 Mac apps, [VLC](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/5758/vlc-media-player) and [Transmission](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/19378/transmission) are included. It helps you keep all your apps updated, and one of its features is download history. This may be an easy way to know which apps to reinstall on a new system.

The app is called [MacUpdate Desktop](http://www.macupdate.com/desktop/membership/), and it's $20/year.

Comment: Do they have an app?

Comment: They do! For $20/year... http://www.macupdate.com/desktop/

Comment: Trying it out now. Seems to be a pretty good app, but I don't know about paying $20 for it, much less $20/year

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

- http://macapps.link/
- http://0install.net/
- getmacapps
- dawt
- calm

I've used all 3 and they are in order from smaller/simpler to larger/more intensive with 0install being dependent on a Homebrew Installation.

Check them all out to find the best fit for your situation. Also I'd like to mention that although it isn't available on these sites (or even their own 3rd party build section for that matter), Pale Moon IS available for macs! It's tucked away in its own little forum on the main Pale Moon site. So, if you use Firefox or Waterfox, IMHO PMoon completely blows them away, and they have NO future plans to drop XUL Extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [HackStore](http://www.hack-store.com/).

> HackStore it is an amazing free alternative of App Store for side developers and apps for Mac OS which Apple doesnt accept.

If you're wondering about the name, read their [FAQ](http://www.hack-store.com/faq).

> **What the main purpose of HackStore?**
>
> We created HackStore at April 2012 and main purpose of HackStore is to be alternative home for developers and their apps, provide a best service app platform for our users, even better than AppStore.
>
> In HackStore you can find thousands of unique apps and most of them are completely free.
>
> Furthermore we are against piracy. We are not related to piracy apps from Mac AppStore or any kind of “hacks” in the bad meaning of this word. As you may know, truth definition of world “hack” is “modification” so it is describing us perfectly! We believe that we can make this world better by creating useful app for smart developers and users.